# CSV Partially Working While Using Products Import

Tags: magento-1.9, products, csv

How can i solve CSV partially working error. Single products CSV working instead of 80 products of CSV import. Format good, bulk products import is the error.

Comment: add your error.

Comment: you mean log error ??

Comment: pls join chat..\